# generate matrix without ams package

Tags: matrices, plain-tex

The science magazine prescribes that authors cannot use 'amsmath' package and so on, then how to generate matrix with Latex?[image]

Comment: as arrays: `\begin{array}  ... `end{array}`. for parenthesis and brackets  use `\left(` or `\[` and `\right)` or `\right]`. welcome to tex.se!

Comment: It sounds like they don't want matrices displayed at all. If you use tabular or tikz matrix they will probably prohibit that as well.  Actually, they don't seem to want any math at all.

Comment: @Zarko : I think the magazine instructions _do not_ want the `array` environment to be used.

Comment: They say that they prefer Word and any LaTeX document will be converted to Word using DOS via HTML... https://www.sciencemag.org/site/feature/contribinfo/prep/TeX_help/ Quite unexpected for "one of the world's top academic journals" (according to Wikipedia).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand the instructions correctly, you need to use the plain TeX version of `\matrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$$\left( \matrix{ a & b & c \cr
d & e & f \cr
g & h & i \cr} \right)$$

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can change the delimiters if you wish. Note that normally you should avoid `$$..$$` in favor of `\[..\]` ([see this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/125871)). However, I see you are specifically instructed by this magazine to use it.

Comment: Thank you very much! Have a good time and God bless you!

Comment: And I just try it, finding that substituting \[ for $$ do not affect the result. So It is not necessary for me to see the post. Hope my idea could negligibly help you. Thanks!

Comment: When using '\[', the last \cr should be deleted.

Answer (score 3):

You need not to use `\left(` and `\right)` when rounded parentheses are used. Just use `\pmatrix` intead `\matrix`. And the last `\cr` is always optional.

```
$$
  \pmatrix{ a & b & c \cr
            d & e & f \cr
            g & h & i }
$$
```